How to process data in Spring WebFlux service without blocking. Exception block() not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
I have a requirement to get results from database and process the two records.
    Flux<CurrencyRate> currenciesFlux = currencyRepository.findByCurrencyNameIn(List.of(from,to))
            .map(CurrencyService::fromModel);

I get 2 records (Flux), and My next step is to divide one by the other.
If I use .collectList().block() to get List , I get exception as expected

java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2

How to process data and return Mono < BigDecimal > ?
Example : ( not exactly like the below , but on similar lines)

convertedRate =
firstElement.getRate().divide(secondElement.getRate(), 3,
RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);


why not use Mono<T> someList = Flux.collectList().flatMap(list -> { ... });

I think that is also a block call

collectList is not blocking, why would you think that? All collect list does is buffering the emitted objects until n items, then it produced a list of n items.

I some how looked at values (a,b) and came up with this
    return currencyRepository.findByCurrencyNameIn(..)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ONE, (a, b) -> b.getCurrencyName().equals(from) ?
                    a.equals(BigDecimal.ONE) ? b.getRate() :  a.divide(b.getRate(),3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)  :
                    a.equals(BigDecimal.ONE) ? b.getRate() :  b.getRate().divide(a,3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));

may be this can be refactored , but ok for now.
